# How to find what Flutter packages requre SDK version #33?

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

When trying to deploy my Flutter app,  I'm getting an error that says that the deployment requires SDK version #33.

How can I find what packages in the app require SDK #33?

R

```
unning Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: The plugin url_launcher_android requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to D:\Ian\Documents\github\good_day\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

android>app>build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion 33
```

Comment: I get that.  I'm trying to find out what packages within the app are forcing the use of SDK #33

Comment: @user2868835 It should say in your logs. Post the full logs.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the log info

Comment: @user2868835 It says it right there in the logs. `Warning: The plugin url_launcher_android requires Android SDK version 33.` Just a heads up about future comments, I don't get notified unless you `@` me.